# Why components disappears and reappears while fast scrolling

Tags: reactjs

Here is the link of the website https://ecom-website-f483.vercel.app/ after website homepage is completely loaded and then if you scroll little faster you will start seeing blank screen and after few milliseconds component appears again.

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: I don't know what is the problem I went through every component. Should I share GitHub code.